# Output HTML string from Json with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Using jQuery I'm trying to output Json data containing a big chunk of HTML. This results in the HTML is being printed out in plain text, because it puts quotations marks around it. I want it as formated HTML. How can I achieve this? It's Json data from the Reddit API.

**My jQuery**

```
    $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/.json', function(data) {

    $.each(data.data.children.slice(0,5), function(key, val) {

        longHTML += '<div class="post">'+val.data.selftext_html+'</div><hr>'

    });

      $(".reddit-content").html(longHTML);

});
```

**Results in**

```
<div class="post">"<!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><h3><a href="#fnatic-logo"></a> Fnatic 0-2 <a href="#vp-logo"> ... etc etc ... <hr/> </div><!-- SC_ON -->"</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the API is returning HTML with all the special characters replaced with their entities. So they get displayed literally. I'm not sure why they're doing that.

Comment: From the reddit [API documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/JSON): NOTE: The HTML string will be escaped. You must unescape to get the raw HTML.

Comment: $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/.json', function(data) {
   var longHTML = "";
    $.each(data.data.children.slice(0,5), function(key, val) {
        var temp = $.parseHTML(val.data.selftext_html);
  if(temp){
            longHTML += '<div class="post">' + $(temp).text() + '</div><hr>'; 
        }else{
         longHTML += '<div class=\"post\">'+temp+'</div><hr>'
        }
    });

      $(".reddit-content").html(longHTML);

}); See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hexjrbcb/

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
$(".reddit-content").html($(longHTML));
```

By passing HTML code into jQuery() it creates the corresponding DOM out of it.

Comment: The `.html()` function does that  by itself. You don't need to call `jQuery()` first.

Comment: You're right of course. Somehow i was thinking of `.append()` and even there i'm not sure if it's needed to pass it to jQuery() first...

Comment: No, that doesn't need it, either